# How to pass font-spec attributes as arguments to set-face-attribute?

Tags: elisp

Suppose that I have some font-spec in a variable `my-font-spec`.  E.g.

```
(setq my-font-spec (font-spec :family "XYZ"
                              :height 120
                              :weight 'normal
                              :width 'normal))
```

I want to pass the attributes in this font-spec as the `&rest` arguments to [`set-face-attribute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html).  IOW, I want to, in effect, invoke

```
(set-face-attribute some-face nil
                    :family "XYZ"
                    :height 120
                    :weight 'normal
                    :width 'normal)
```

but do so without spelling out the attributes (as I've done above), but rather indirectly, through some function of `my-font-spec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but calling `(font-face-attributes my-font-spec)` doesn't return the value of the `:height` attribute you specified:

```
(:family "XYZ" :weight normal :width normal)
```

If it did, you could just call:

```
(apply 'set-face-attribute some-face nil (font-face-attributes my-font-spec))
```

But to make sure to get the values of all the specified attributes, you can instead get a full list of attributes using the `face-attribute-name-alist` variable, retrieve the value of each (if present) from `my-font-spec`, and then apply them to `some-face`:

```
(let (props)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (attrval)
              (let* ((attr (car attrval))
                     (prop (font-get my-font-spec attr)))
                (if prop
                    (progn (push prop props)
                           (push attr props))))) face-attribute-name-alist)
  (apply 'set-face-attribute some-face nil props))
```